# Not able to see test webpage remotely but can ping the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a test server that I can ping successfully although I'm not able to see a hello world test page I've created and mapped in IIS.  I've also created an Inbound rule in the windows firewall.  Is there something else I'm missing?  I'm browsing http://x.x.x.x:888

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

**Update**

- This is a AWS server
- Have tried telnet from a client machine but I get Operation timed out
- Nothing in IIS logs (C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\xxx)
- Port 888 is what I assign the test website to in IIS
- Have also moved the test file (index.htm) into the default website within IIS and tried browsing http://x.x.x.x:80/index.htm but I get This site can’t be reached
- browsing http://localhost on the server displays the 'hello' message test page.
- In windows explorer I've gone to the security settings by right clicking on the website folder and allowing 'everyone' read access

**Firewall screen shot**

[image]

**Important update**

- the IP http://x.x.x.x:888 is the public IP within AWS for the server, not the interal IP of that actual server

Comment: What do you actually get when you try and hit the page? what error exactly? If a ping works, the next thing to try is a telnet test to see if the port is open. In this case type `telnet x.x.x.x 123` (space not colon) and you should get a mostly blank screen (as opposed to an error)

Comment: and you can ping it from the source computer right? (not from the web server)

Comment: I can ping it from a different machine yes.  When trying to access the page through the browser on a different internet enabled machine it tries to connect for a long time (a minute or so) and then displays "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: After you've tried the telnet thing, also check the IIS logs to see if it is detecting your HTTP GET, There's two things to try.

Comment: I cannot telnet, I get Operation timed out.  I haven't installed telnet server on the web server - I can, just didn't think it was needed for making a web server

Comment: No telnet is not needed to run  a web server. It's just a handy test tool. If you ran telnet from the client and it did not connect (I'm not sure from your response), then you have probably forwarded your ports incorrectly. Normally a web server runs on port 80 (you didn't say) so your firewall needs to redirect all incoming requests on port 123 to port 80 on your web server. Where did you get the 123 from in the first place and what port is your web server running on?

Comment: Just to confirm telnet from the client machine did not work

Comment: OK so we need to focus on that firewall. I guess all of this is on a LAN right? So just to confirm, your firewall rule allows incoming connections on port 123? Don't use the named "World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In)" as that opens port 80, and you aren't using port 80.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect your questions, p.s I've changed the port to 888 just to see if it made a difference but it didn't

Comment: That looks like just the internal windows firewall. I believe there is another AWS firewall called a 'security group' that you need to configure also. Here's a link to read: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-application-server.html. Go the the ECS management here: 
https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/ then click on security groups and set it up just like a firewall. I'm off to bed now- good luck I'll check back in about 10 hours

Comment: How did you go opening the AWS firewall?

Comment: I guess it worked and you're so busy playing with AWS you can't respond.

Answer (score -1):

On windows 10, I found a firewall issue for my testing server, this worked for me: go to `Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Windows Firewall properties` and set a public profile to allow incoming connections.